# Append the specific column in another existing table using SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, join, rdbms

I know it sounds easy when appending a entire row to new table, but this is different

[image: This is Table 1]

[image: This is Table 2]

[image: This is Table 3]

Question 1, state to combine the Table 1 and Table 2 and keep duplicate value, to create a new table, I have used the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE EMP_TBL_3
(
    EMP_ID int,
    Name varchar(255),
    DOJ int
);

INSERT INTO EMP_TBL_3 (EMP_ID, Name, DOJ)
   SELECT * FROM EMP_TBL_1 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM EMP_TBL_2;
```

Results:

[image: Answer]

Now the problem arise at 2nd question, saying: Take the D.O.B from EMP_BRTH_REC and combine them to EMP_TBL_3:

I have tried this query:

```
ALTER TABLE EMP_TBL_3
ADD DOB int;

SELECT * FROM EMP_TBL_3;

SELECT EMP_ID, Name, DOJ, DOB
FROM EMP_TBL_3
UNION ALL
SELECT EMP_TBL_3.EMP_ID, EMP_TBL_3.Name, EMP_TBL_3.DOJ, EMP_BRTH_REC.DOB
FROM EMP_BRTH_REC 
LEFT JOIN EMP_TBL_3 ON EMP_BRTH_REC.EMP_ID = EMP_TBL_3.EMP_ID;
```

Results:

[image: Error Result]

My desired output is:

[image]

How do I do that?

Comment: So you're attempting this on 3 type of DBMS?

Comment: I've removed the RDBMS tags - please add back the one of interest.

Comment: tcadidot0 Correct

Comment: Dale K, I've added the tag!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i undertand propery, you just need to do this:

```
select EMP_TBL_3.EMP_ID, EMP_TBL_3.Name, EMP_TBL_3.DOJ, EMP_BRTH_REC.DOB
from EMP_BRTH_REC LEFT JOIN
     EMP_TBL_3
     on EMP_BRTH_REC.EMP_ID = EMP_TBL_3.EMP_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are twice inserting the records using UNION ALL. I would suggest you to truncate and reload data into Tbl3 as given below:

```
ALTER TABLE EMP_TBL_3
ADD DOB int;

TRUNCATE TABLE Emp_Tbl_3;

INSERT INTO Emp_Tbl_3(Emp_Id, Name, DOJ, DOB)
SELECT EMP_TBL_1.EMP_ID, EMP_TBL_1.Name, EMP_TBL_1.DOJ, EMP_BRTH_REC.DOB
from 
EMP_BRTH_REC 
LEFT JOIN EMP_TBL_1
on EMP_BRTH_REC.EMP_ID = EMP_TBL_1.EMP_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT EMP_TBL_2.EMP_ID, EMP_TBL_2.Name, EMP_TBL_2.DOJ, EMP_BRTH_REC.DOB
from 
EMP_BRTH_REC 
LEFT JOIN EMP_TBL_2
on EMP_BRTH_REC.EMP_ID = EMP_TBL_2.EMP_ID;
```

Comment: This is right, but am getting additional 8 rows instead! i need only 8 rows